# Problem from the book Number Fields by Marcus

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I have been stuck on the 14(c)th problem of the 3rd chapter from Marcus' Number Fields. 
Let $K$ and $L$ be number fields, $K \subset L$,  $R = \mathbb{A}\cap K$, $S = \mathbb{A} \cap  L$. Moreover assume that $L$ is normal over $K$. Let $G$ denote the Galois group of $L$ over $K$.
For an ideal $I$ of $S$, define the norm $N(I)$ to be the ideal $R \cap {\displaystyle \prod_{\sigma \in G}  \sigma(I)}$.
Show that for an ideal $I$ of $S$,  ${\displaystyle \prod_{\sigma \in G}  \sigma(I)} = (N(I))S$

(Here $R$ and $S$ are number rings corresponding to the number fields $K$ and $L$ respectively)

I want to follow the hints given there.But I got stuck at one point. I can't show that "the product has the form $JS$ for some ideal $J$ of $R$".I am able to solve this problem if I assume the above fact.
Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $I=\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots \mathfrak{p}_k$, with the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ prime ideals of $S$ (not necessarily distinct). Then
$$ \prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(I)=\prod_{i=1}^k\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)$$

If you did the previous part, then you know that
$$ \prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_i)=P_i^{f_i}S $$
where $P_i$ is the prime of $R$ lying below $\mathfrak{p}_i$. Therefore $\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(I)=JS$ for $J=\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{f_i}$.

Comment: The previous part (b) says $R\cap \Pi\sigma(Q)=P^{f(Q|P)}$. How does it follow that $\Pi\sigma(Q)=P^{f(Q|P)}S$ as your second equation says? May you explain it? Thank you.

Comment: Let $P$ be a prime in $R$, and let $\mathfrak{p}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{p}_r$ be the primes in $S$ lying above $P$. Then by part (a) of the problem, there are $ef$ elements $\sigma\in G$ such that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_1)=\mathfrak{p}_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$, hence $\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(\mathfrak{p}_1)=\prod_{i=1}^r\mathfrak{p}_i^{ef}=(PS)^f$.